# Riddling for fun

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Ladies and gentlemen,
I will defend you.
I am not a comedian,
but will entertain you.

I can’t be dangerous,
yet my half-name is.
Can you name me the hero
of this colorful quiz?

---

Time for the first hint:

> I am good at bringing joy,
>  maybe that’s why they call me toy.

Btw. one of you all is very very close to the answer.

Comment: One thing that is tripping me up is the location of the word "colorful". The clue says that the *quiz* is colorful. It doesn't say that the *hero* is colorful. Am I interpreting this correctly? (Sorry for thinking out loud... first comment on the entire site!)

Comment: Good question. The quiz is colorful, because fun is sometimes associated with a mix of many colors. But the hero is also colorful. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First time here!

I think it's

> toy gun

Explanation:

**I will defend you.**

> That's how kids think of toy guns often.

**will entertain you**

> You know, a kids' toy. It's for fun.

**I can’t be dangerous,**

> It's fake. It's plastic. Not much danger.

**yet my half-name is.**

> Unlike toy-guns, just **guns** are dangerous.

**of this colorful quiz?**

> Per OPs comment on his question, the "hero" can just sometimes be colorful. It's not uncommon for toy guns to be colored.

**Edit:**

Ah, probably:

> nerf gun

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: @crazyiman done. Thanks — sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, very warm. This is actually generalisation of your answer. :) Can you be more specific? I am looking for a particular type. That is always very colorful, pretty nerdy, no dangerous at all and mountains of fun.

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi oh, hmm. Do you mean that the correct answer is a generalization of my answer, or my answer is a generalization of the correct answer?

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobiwait wait, I think I got it. See edit. :)

Comment: sorry :) you are right.. your answer is generalisation of the correct answer.. to late to think...

Comment: Was about to post, but you beat me to it. Sounds right to me!

Comment: @Chris I wonder if the "correct answer" might be water gun if it isn't nerf gun.  Those are many times brightly colored as well.

Comment: Isn't "I will defend you" a bit of a stretch here?

Answer (score 26):

Think it must be:

> Magnetosphere

Ladies and gentlemen
I will defend you.

> Protect us from solar wind

I am not a comedian
but will entertain you.

> Northern lights are very entertaining

I can’t be dangerous,
yet my half-name is.

> Magneto is a comic book villain

Can you name me the hero
of this colorful quiz?

> Northern lights are very colorful

Comment: good guess, given almost all my previous riddles are connected with computer science/astronomy/physics. However, not what I had in mind. Just as a small hint, the answer this time has nothing to do with this topics.. But it is nerdy as well :)

Answer (score 17):

My answer:

> Condom

Ladies and gentlemen

> There are male and female condoms

I will defend you.

> Protect from STIs

I am not a comedian
but will entertain you.

> Many are designed specifically to increase pleasure

I can’t be dangerous,
yet my half-name is.

> A 'con' is certainly a negative/dangerous thing

Can you name me the hero
of this colorful quiz?

> Condoms come in many colors

Comment: funny answer :) but nope. The entertaining and the colorful parts do not fit perfectly. Otherwise. very amusing and original.

Comment: I've seen this item as a guess to the answer of loads of riddles ... so many dirty-minded people around :-o

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi: I had a feeling it was wrong, but it seemed to mostly fit... That's why I gave a second more serious answer as well.

Comment: @randal'thor defend? protection? entertain?  colorful?  That sounds familar lol

Answer (score 7):

First time here :)

Ladies and gentlemen

> Sunglasses are for both

I will defend you

> Sunglasses protect your eyes from damaging sunrays

I am not a comedian but will entertain you.

> Funny sunglasses are pretty common

I can’t be dangerous

> Sunglasses aren't dangerous (unless your poke your eye with it)

yet my half-name is

> Sun is dangerous

Can you name me the hero of this colorful quiz?

> Sunglasses come in many colors

Comment: it is not the answer, but the "dangerous" part made me laugh so hard.. :)

Answer (score 5):

It's my first time here in STEX Puzzling. I don't know the rules, but here's my try:

> Spider-man

Ladies and gentlemen,
I will defend you.

> He defends people from villains

I am not a comedian,
but will entertain you.

> Entertains you whenever he saves people or when he takes photographs that are published in Daily Bugle

I can’t be dangerous,
yet my half-name is.

> A spider <s>man</s> could be venomous.

Can you name me the hero
of this colorful quiz?

> He is a hero from colorful comic books

Comment: also you said it's nerdy, although I don't know what kind of nerdy you are talking about :)

Comment: Welcome to puzzling :) Very good start, actually. This is not the right answer, but awesome guess and nerdy interpretation. Spiders can be dangerous, indeed, but not always. I'll post a hint in few hours, it might help.

Answer (score 4):

A very wild guess:

> [Snapdragon SOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualcomm_Snapdragon) that is used in phones, GPS, car infotaintment systems etc.

Ladies and gentlemen,

> Targets both

I will defend you.

> Saves through GPS, presenting info, timers, processing sensors to avoid accidents etc

I am not a comedian,

> It is just an SOC

but will entertain you.

> Games, videos, audios etc

I can’t be dangerous,

> Almost never

yet my half-name is.

> snap + dragon

Can you name me the hero

of this colorful quiz?

> snapdragon plants are quite colorful. Moreover the graphics presented by this can be colorful.

Big chances are this is not the answer that was in your mind, but if fits.

Comment: You are right, is not the hero in the riddle, but a lot of the clues fit very well. :) However, dragons are not definitely dangerous, or are they? As far as I recall, in the Eastern mythology, some of them bring rain and good stuff.

Answer (score 4):

This is a wild guess but what about

> Rainbow

Ladies and gentlemen,

> Just a greeting

I will defend you.

> In Game of Thrones there is a Rainbow guard used to protect king Renly

I am not a comedian,

> It is not

but will entertain you.

> Everyone like to look at the rainbow. Double rainbow all the way

I can’t be dangerous,

> Rainbow can't hurt you

yet my half-name is.

> Half name is bow - which is certainly dangerous

Can you name me the hero

> I just did

of this colorful quiz?

> Rainbow is colorful

Comment: Funny answer, indeed :) The clue with the defence does not really fit, but apart from that, I totally enjoyed the word play with the half-name. Yes, bows can be dangerous!

Comment: The defense fits as well, but I agree, it's too specific and obscure. It was worth a try :)

Answer (score 4):

I think it is

> Ad-Blocker

Ladies and gentlemen,

> everyone uses it

I will defend you.

> blocks ads

I am not a comedian,
but will entertain you.

> less ads = more fun browsing, watching videos etc

I can’t be dangerous,
yet my half-name is.

> ads can be dangerous, full of spam and redirect to malicious sites

Can you name me the hero
of this colorful quiz?

> Alot of ad are colorful, rich in color, trying to grab attention. There is often ads that asks questions like "Would you like A or B" or "What are you waiting for?" etc

Comment: Interesting idea :) not the right one, though. It is also interesting to see what you guys perceive as dangerous :D

Answer (score 3):

My wild guess would be

> Painball gun

Ladies and gentlemen,

> Targets both

I will defend you.

> You use it to defend yourself

I am not a comedian,

> Of course it's not!

but will entertain you.

> Isn't it fun?

I can’t be dangerous,

> They can hurt, but they aren't dangerous(unless you do some very stupid things)

yet my half-name is.

> Ok, I didn't understand this line :(

Can you name me the hero
of this colorful quiz?

> Paintball guns use those paint pellets and they are normally of different colors ==> they are colorful

Comment: very good guess, I would say.. But nope. Paintball guns are actually dangerous, that's why the players are wearing protective equipment. :)

Answer (score 3):

Is it a

> Puppy?

Ladies and gentlemen,
I will defend you.

> Puppy defends!

I am not a comedian,
but will entertain you.

> It's fun to play with puppies

I can’t be dangerous,

> >! Puppy isn't dangerous I guess

yet my half-name is.

> (Pu), which is Plutonium in peroidic table, a transuranic radioactive chemical element

Can you name me the hero

> Plutonium, named after [Pluto](http://camphalfblood.wikia.com/wiki/Pluto)

of this colorful quiz?

> And Plutonium is [colorful](http://chemistry.about.com/od/imagesclipartstructures/ig/Science-Pictures/Plutonium-Colors.htm) (well not that colorful maybe..)

Comment: Plutonium is dangerous, no doubt.. :) The answer I'm looking for is much obvious and easier... And has normally very annoyng colours.

Comment: hm I will think again, much obvious....

Answer (score 2):

Another first timer here. I think it is:

> Water pistol

Ladies and gentlemen,

> It's a unisex toy

I will defend you.

> People will think twice before picking on you if you've got a water gun pointed at them

I am not a comedian,

> Nope

but will entertain you.

> Yeah! It's fun right?

I can’t be dangerous,

> Unless someone is to put salt accid in it

yet my half-name is.

> PISTOL!

Can you name me the hero
of this colorful quiz?

> Comes in many colors

Cheers from the netherlands.

Comment: few minutes too late.. :) Chris already gave the right answer. But impressive first guess! Welcome to puzzling!

Comment: Yeah, just saw it. Damn! I'll try another one :D

Answer (score 1):

My guess is

> Alarm Clock

Ladies and gentlemen,

> Used by both genders

I will defend you.

> Against over sleeping

I am not a comedian,

> Of course Mr. serious.

but will entertain you.

> Different tones and music

I can’t be dangerous,

> Waking you up doesn't mean harming you.

yet my half-name is.

> Isn't that 'alarm'ing ?

Can you name me the hero

> very very helpful.

of this colorful quiz?

> Nice rhyming prose.

Comment: some clues do not fit, but nice try :)

Comment: @ziobi.wan.Kenobi thank you for the encouragement. Still thinking.....

Comment: if you are stuck, read the answers from the peers :) one of them is really really close...